# Unable to find suitable version for underscore

Tags: bower

I get the following error:

```
Message:
    Unable to find suitable version for underscore
Details:
    code: ECONFLICT
    picks: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

With the following bower file, this error I have never come across before. I cannot use the interactive shell, as this gets deployed to continuous integration. We also prefer to use Github repo links (don't ask me why) over bower packages.

```
{
    "name": "Nightbird",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "main": "src/css/style.scss",
    "dependencies": {
      "backbone": "git@github.com:jashkenas/backbone.git#1.1.2",
      "underscore": "git@github.com:jashkenas/underscore.git#1.6.0",
      "aisis-bootstrap-theme": "git@github.com:AdamKyle/Aisis-Bootstrap-Theme.git#0.5.0",
      "selectize.js": "git@github.com:brianreavis/selectize.js.git#0.8",
      "underscore.string": "git@github.com:epeli/underscore.string.git#v2.3.2",
      "jquery-bootpag": "git@github.com:botmonster/jquery-bootpag.git#1.0.5",
      "underscore.inflection": "git@github.com:jeremyruppel/underscore.inflection.git",
      "moment": "git@github.com:moment/moment.git",
      "bootstrap-markdown": "git@github.com:toopay/bootstrap-markdown.git#2.5.0",
      "markdown-js": "git@github.com:evilstreak/markdown-js.git#v0.5.0",
      "to-markdown": "git@github.com:domchristie/to-markdown.git#v0.0.2",
      "font-awesome": "git@github.com:FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#4.2.0",
      "react-bower": "git@github.com:reactjs/react-bower.git#0.11.1",
      "showdown": "git@github.com:coreyti/showdown.git#0.3.1",
      "pure": "git@github.com:yahoo/pure.git#0.5.0"
    }
}
```

Any idea whats going on? Is this a bug? or just a developer being dumb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a conflict between 3 different versions of underscore.
The reason for this is that underscore is required by 3 of your dependencies: Nightbird, backbone and underscore.inflection.
Using the latest version of Bower you can see the following information:

```
Unable to find a suitable version for underscore, please choose one:
    1) underscore#1.6.0 which resolved to 1.6.0 and is required by Nightbird
    2) underscore#>=1.5.0 which resolved to 1.6.0 and is required by backbone#1.1.2
    3) underscore#~1.7.0 which resolved to 1.7.0 and is required by underscore.inflection#1.2.0
```

You can force bower to use a specific version in case of resolution by adding the following to your bower.json. In this example it will force using 1.6.0:

```
"resolutions": {
  "underscore": "1.6.0"
}
```